# POST dynamically created required input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

This is the code I'm using to POST data, it works, the problem appeared after I have added a required parameter, now the code forces to fill all fields even if they are are not visible. I guess the problem is in `hide()` function in jQuery because it only hides the field. What changes should be applied to make this code require only visible fields?

```js
$('#product_type').change(refresh_inputs);
refresh_inputs();
function refresh_inputs() {
    var name = $('#product_type').attr('name');
    var val = $('#product_type').val();
    $('#'+name+' div').hide();
    $('#'+val).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="add.php" method="post" name="form1" >
    <table width="25%" border="0">
        <tr> 
            <td>SKU</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sku" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Price</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price" required></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select product type</td>
            <td>
                <select id="product_type" name="products" required>
                    <option style="display: none;" selected>Select product type</option>
                    <option value="book">Book</option>
                    <option value="dvd">Dvd</option>
                    <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="products">
                    <div id="book">
                        <input type="text" name="weight" placeholder="Weight" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="dvd">
                        <input type="text" name="capacity" placeholder="Capacity" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="furniture">
                        <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="Height" required/>
                        <input type="text" name="width" placeholder="Width" required/>
                        <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Length" required/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You could use the jQuery `.remove()` function instead `.hide()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify refresh_inputs function as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#product_type').change(refresh_inputs);
    refresh_inputs();
    function refresh_inputs() {
        var name = $('#product_type').attr('name');
        var val = $('#product_type').val();
        $('#'+name+' div').hide();
        $('#'+name+' div').find('input').removeAttr('required');
        $('#'+val).show();
        $('#'+val).find('input').attr('required', 'required');
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It almost does the thing, but now when i'm submitting Weight field it clones value into Length field, and when I'm adding furniture it adds only first 2 fields

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not due to my code because all I am doing is adding and removing the required attribute from the element. That must be another issue.

Comment: That's right, just tested, problem is in another file :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#product_type').change(refresh_inputs);
        refresh_inputs();
        function refresh_inputs() {
            var name = $('#product_type').attr('name');
            var val = $('#product_type').val();
            $('#'+name+' div').attr("required", false); // add this line only
            $('#'+name+' div').hide();
            $('#'+val).show();
         }
</script>
```

It hides the element not removing the property set by yourself as required.